# Creating and scaling SVG for printer output

Tags: pdf, layout, canvas, svg

I have an app which creates a basic svg tile which is about 300 x 150px. I need to duplicate this tile, such that I can create a nice printout on two A4 pages, or a single A3 page. So, basically, I'm just doing page layout 101, in svg rather than Photoshop/whatever.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to start this? At the moment, I'm doing it very naively:

1. set a large canvas, of about 1500 x 1500px
2. duplicate the tile 4 x 6 times in JavaScript
3. print from the browser

This is more-or-less passable, but doesn't look good. Would it help to set up a canvas with a physical size of an A4 page? If I do this, I then have the problem that the tile is a complex graphic which I have currently created using pixel units. Even if I do this, the browser will presumably ignore the canvas size anyway. Or should I convert to pdf first? If I do this, I still need to work out how to set up an svg 'page' that will convert well to pdf. And do any tools actually support the svg 1.2 page stuff?

Note that I can't use Inkscape, since my svg code is entirely JavaScript.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots to show the way in which it doesn't look good? If you can supply a jsfiddle that would be ideal, as people can get a feel for what is going wrong. Also, how are you converting from SVG to PDF? Presumably you are doing that bit on the server?

Comment: Imagine a Word doc printed on A4 in which 10pt text comes out as 14pt, the right margin is way off, and in which the page breaks have been lost, and you're there. I hadn't tried pdf conversion before posting, but I've now tried wkhtmltopdf. If I set up the canvas as 297x210mm, and run wkhtmltopdf without smart scaling, and with zero margins, the output will fit on one A4 page, albeit not quite centred. The problem then is finding something to set the viewbox to which is logical and which lets me design in pixels. I think I may have to give up pixels and move to pts and cm.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use canvas for this!

The point of SVG is scalable graphics. You can just scale the SVG yourself in the browser and then print from there.

If you want to scale SVG then all you have to do is either apply a CSS scale:

http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/xYZyf/

Or an SVG scale:

http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/xYZyf/1/

Comment: CSS scale doesn't seem to work in webkit-based browsers as of July 2014